# React JS Cards using For loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, for-loop

I can't manage to dynamically produce more than one 'Card' in my React webpage. I import the data from database.js, but I'm clearly not implementing the For loop correctly.

I've tried the loop in a function outside the render() but that didn't work. I need the for loop to produce however many objects I have in the database, but I'm stuck on one. I can call the data within the {} in the thml code, but that's about it.

**projects.js**

````
class Projects extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { activeTab: 1 };
    }

    toggleCategories() {
        if (this.state.activeTab === 1) {
            for (let data of database) {
                return (
                    <div className='projects-grid'>
                        <Card shadow={4} style={{ minWidth: '450', margin: 'auto' }}>
                            <CardTitle style={{height: '250px', background: data.image }}></CardTitle>
                            <CardText>
                                {data.name}
                            </CardText>
                            <CardActions border>
                                <Button colored>GitHub</Button>
                                <Button colored>Live Demo</Button>
                            </CardActions>
                        </Card>
                    </div>
                )
            }
        }```

**database.js**

let database = [
  {
    name: 'Trombinoscope',
    image: 'url(https://i.ibb.co/g4mT3K5/html-Css-Js.jpg)',
    description: 'Group project',
    languages: 'HTML, CSS, JavaScript'
  },
  {
    name: 'CRUD System',
    image: 'url(https://i.ibb.co/g4mT3K5/html-Css-Js.jpg)',
    description: 'Video game database',
    languages: 'PHP, SQL'
  }
]

export default database;


Any help would be appreciated.
````

Comment: You're not looping. You're *starting* a loop, but then doing a `return` on the first loop iteration, which stops the loop. Is `toggleCategories` supposed to render all of those cards?

Comment: `toggleCategories` is used to select which type of project I will show. I'll add an If statement at some point to show just valid data, but I haven't got that far yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you aren't returning anything from toggleCategories.

would this work?

````
class Projects extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { activeTab: 1 };
    }

    toggleCategories() {
        if (this.state.activeTab === 1) {
            return database.map(data => {
               return (
                    <div className='projects-grid'>
                        <Card shadow={4} style={{ minWidth: '450', margin: 'auto' }}>
                            <CardTitle style={{height: '250px', background: data.image }}></CardTitle>
                            <CardText>
                                {data.name}
                            </CardText>
                            <CardActions border>
                                <Button colored>GitHub</Button>
                                <Button colored>Live Demo</Button>
                            </CardActions>
                        </Card>
                    </div>
            })

        }```

**database.js**

let database = [
  {
    name: 'Trombinoscope',
    image: 'url(https://i.ibb.co/g4mT3K5/html-Css-Js.jpg)',
    description: 'Group project',
    languages: 'HTML, CSS, JavaScript'
  },
  {
    name: 'CRUD System',
    image: 'url(https://i.ibb.co/g4mT3K5/html-Css-Js.jpg)',
    description: 'Video game database',
    languages: 'PHP, SQL'
  }
]

export default database;
````

Comment: Thanks, guys. Using database.map(data => ) is the way forward.

Comment: @JamesRossCodes Just wanted to let OP know what he was doing wrong

Answer (score 1):

You're not looping. You're *starting* a loop, but then doing a `return` on the first loop iteration, which stops the loop. If `toggleCategories` is supposed to render all of those cards, the usual thing is to use `map` and return an array:

```
toggleCategories() {
    if (this.state.activeTab === 1) {
        return database.map(data => (
            <div className='projects-grid'>
                <Card shadow={4} style={{ minWidth: '450', margin: 'auto' }}>
                    <CardTitle style={{height: '250px', background: data.image }}></CardTitle>
                    <CardText>
                        {data.name}
                    </CardText>
                    <CardActions border>
                        <Button colored>GitHub</Button>
                        <Button colored>Live Demo</Button>
                    </CardActions>
                </Card>
            </div>
        ));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't return Cards in loop, it will return on first iteration. Create an array and push cards in that array.

```js
toggleCategories() {
      const catrgories = [];
        if (this.state.activeTab === 1) {
            for (let data of database) {
                catrgories.push(
                    <div className='projects-grid'>
                        <Card shadow={4} style={{ minWidth: '450', margin: 'auto' }}>
                            <CardTitle style={{height: '250px', background: data.image }}></CardTitle>
                            <CardText>
                                {data.name}
                            </CardText>
                            <CardActions border>
                                <Button colored>GitHub</Button>
                                <Button colored>Live Demo</Button>
                            </CardActions>
                        </Card>
                    </div>
                );
         }
    }
}


// use it like

{toggleCategories()}
```